# Kafka - Ensuring that at least one consumer will receive the message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, messaging

I am building a distributed application and I decided to introduce Kafka to it. I am however having a tough time figuring out something.

I understand that having a consumer group ensures HA and high message throughput. Each consumer in the group though is "following" only one partition in the topic. Let's say for example that we have 1 topic with 4 partition and one consumer group with 4 consumers. Each consumer, as mentioned earlier, will get messages only from its designated partition.

Now let's say that we have a number of producers publish messages to the topic. One producer writes a message to partition 1 of the topic and consumer 1 receives it and performs some logic with it so it is busy. Then another message is published but to the same partition. None of the other consumers will be able to receive it as they the partition does not "belong" to them.

I am looking for a way that whenever a new message is produced at least one idle consumer will receive it instantly even if it is not written to its partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this will not be possible with Kafka. As you correctly described, there can only be at most one consumer out of a group that reads one partition. That way you ensure ordering of the messages within a partition.

What you could do to prevent the application to get even slower when one of the consumer dies is to have more consumers than partitions. That way you will have some idle consumers that can keep up with the state of the actual consuming consumers and jump-in quickly if one of the working consumers dies.

Also you could increase the partitions to avoid having too much load on one of them. Or, as an alternative, and if you know your data in advance, you could have a custom partitioner in your Kafka Producer that distributes the messages in a way that processing can evenly ditributed over the partitions and their consumers.

Comment: Is having only one partition and multiple consumers a valid solution? This way all producers write to the same partition and there is a sense of load balancing among consumers.

Comment: in that scenario you still have only one consumer for the one partition (If the consumers belong to the same consumer group).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.assign()` method instead of `.subscribe()` on your consumers so that they're not in any consumer group. However, this way they will receive all messages from assigned partitions. You might then implement some logic on the client-side to prevent processing messages that are processed by other instances, but anyway you'll end up losing ordering and, most likely, delivery guarantees.

Comment: It is not a possibility, however thanks for your help. I may use another message broker such as RabbitMQ that will provide what I need.

Comment: Sounds like there is no way to publish a message and ensure one and only one consumer processes it?